# Need Javascript showing two hidden css divs

Tags: javascript, html, show, using

the css for #step2 and #step2h are visibility:hidden
this is my current script but I want to show not only #step but #step2h as well in one click with javascript.

```
<body>
<center>
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="content">
<div id="contenth">
<h1 id=>content header</h1>
</div>
content
<a href="#" onclick="changeDiv(1)">Menu 1</a> ///change to other div
<a href="#" onclick="changeDiv(2)">Menu 2</a>
<script>
function changeDiv(i){
if(i==1)
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = document.getElementById("step2").innerHTML;
else
document.getElementById("step2").innerHTML = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML;
}
</script>
</div>
</div>
<div id="step2"> // Showed on click
<div id="step2h">//want to show this as well
<h1>STEP 2 Header</h1>
</div>
<h2>Step 2 Content</h2>

</div>
</center>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Typically you would do something like this:

```
document.getElementById("step2h").style.visibility='visible';
```

The problem you may be facing is that replacing the HTML for step2 is wiping out step2h since it is inside of step2 and thus part of step2's innerHTML.

I would create a step2c div for the step2 content, and have it below step2h. Then replace its contents with the contents of content and you won't lose step2h in the process. Something like this:

```
<div id="step2">
    <div id="step2h">
        <h1>STEP 2 Header</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="step2c">
        <h2>Step 2 Content</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then do this:

```
document.getElementById("step2c").innerHTML = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML;
```